# WIFI not working on one specific wifi network

Tags: wireless

I have a DELL Latitude D630 and Ubuntu 14.04. The WIFI work perfectly with all wifi networks a part from my office wifi network. It used to work in my office until last June but now it is not working anymore. I am wondering is it due to the fact that I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 this summer and I have to re-configure something. Before upgrading I never had to configure wifi networks differently though. They all worked perfectly.
Can you please advise?

I asked my IT department and they confirmed no changes were made to our office wifi network. I saw in other similar questions that the wireless driver may not be configured correctly so the adapter for my office wifi network may not be properly set up. If this is the case can you please advise how to configure the driver correctly? Please also let me know if I have to request from my IT guys the details of the wifi network and what details in particular.

Comment: Are you sure no changes were made with your office network?  I've also never had to reconfigure anything for an upgrade, or new install for that matter.  Just pick the network and possibly enter the password.  You might try forgetting that network, and then reconfiguring it.

Comment: I tried 'Forget network' and then picked it again and entered the correct password but it is not working. I will ask in my office if they changed any configuration but I doubt.

Comment: Also, how old is your router?  Maybe the office changed the protocol to something the router doesn't support (or Ubuntu?).  I've seen a lot of problems seemingly solved by a new router.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do> Must be while trying to connect to the network you are having issues with. Can you connect to other networks with out any issues?

Comment: I run the script and pasted the output into PasteBin - link http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8508753/. I can connect to all other networks fine, I am currently connected to my home network. Today I asked my IT department and they confirmed no changes were made to our office wifi network. Please let me know if you can find the reason for failing to connect to my office wifi network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try the native driver and firmware:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: I've done that and paste the report here http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8545627/.

Comment: Your report shows that the wireless is now connected and has an IP address. If your problem is solved, please accept my answer.

Comment: I just connected to my office wireless network and the connection is perfectly working. Thank you for the support.